# bran in the bathhouse for use as a cleanser

Tags: women, mishna

In Mishna Pesahim ([2:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.2.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> MISHNA: A woman may not soak coarse **bran to bring by
> hand to the bathhouse for use as a cleanser**; however, she may rub
> coarse bran on her dry skin.

Where can we find documentation for this women habit in material culture? Is it documented somewhere except for Mishna or Jewish literature to which I can refer?

Answer (score 3):

A search for “bran as cleanser” turned up:

[Lemon juice with yogurt and wheat bran](https://www.curejoy.com/content/best-natural-exfoliants-for-skin/#:%7E:text=Wheat%20bran%20is%20an%20efficient%20skin%20cleanser%20and,the%20skin%20and%20balances%20the%20pH%20level.%205)

From the article:

> To make a natural skin exfoliant at home, you will typically need: A
> scrub ingredient.  A smooth base. Nourishing/moisturizing/hydrating
> ingredients.

The “scrub  ingredient” is presumably the bran.

And

[Komenuka Bijin Facial Cleansing Powder From Natural Rice Bran](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Komenuka-Facial-Cleansing-Powder-Natural/dp/B000BRY5UI)

> Product description The outer hull of the rice kernel is
> nutrient-dense, packed with over 100 powerful antioxidants like
> skin-renewing Vitamin E, Oryzanol, and Lipoic Acid. Plus, rice bran is
> a natural exfoliant - gentler than fruit extracts which can tear the
> skin.